# How can I switch between open applications?

Tags: window

Pressing `alt` + `tab` brings up a carousel of all the icons of my open applications, and by hitting `tab` I can cycle through them. By releasing `tab` it brings the window of the application I'm currently on to the front of the screen.

But how do I quickly and efficiently jump to an application that has multiple windows open? I often have multiple Terminal windows open, for example. But I have to cycle onto the terminal icon, and then cycle through all of the open terminal windows to find the window I want.

In OSX, an application with multiple windows can still be quickly 'tabbed' into because it opens the last window of the application that you were working on (I think). Can I emulate this behaviour, or at least speed up my workflow in Ubuntu? I want to jump between sublime text and the last terminal window I was working in (of my many terminal windows).

Comment: So do you want a **specific** terminal window or the **last** one? The OSX example you've given mentions the "last window" but you later mention "a specific window" of many.

Comment: Edited question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> will bring up the app switcher but only for windows of that application, if that's what you're looking for.

Also, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will switch through applications by running down the Unity Launcher, and when you open the application with multiple windows, it will automatically open the last active window.

Comment: + 1 for super + tab (for fellow Ubuntu beginners, super is the windows button on PC, the apple button on Mac), but this doesn't work quite as well as in OSX. There you can switch between two applications (the last two you've used, out of many) just by hitting alt + tab. Is the behaviour available? If not, this will probably be the nearest answer.

Comment: Using Alt-Tab will bring up a small overlay of all running applications. Pressing it again will automatically switch to the last opened one (before the active one). Otherwise, I'm not sure what behavior you're describing, as I've never seen such on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

When too many apps are open, searching in the **Activities Overview** can prove to be more useful. **Activities Overview** can be accessed with the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

For example, to quickly switch to using the Google Chrome app :

- Press <kbd>Super</kbd>
- Type prefix "ch" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to using the Google Chrome app.

With this method, you jump directly to the desired app without having to worry about the open windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Tab</kbd>  and get into the application switcher, you can press <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> keys to switch between different windows of the currently highlighted app.

Answer (score 1):

You can create keyboard shortcuts(key bindings) to jump to your preferred apps quickly using [**jumpapp**](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp).

For example, since I am a software engineer who relies on efficiently using the *Terminal*, *Google-Chrome*, and *Visual-Studio-Code* apps a lot, I bound:

- Terminal: `Ctrl + P`
- Google Chome: `Alt + Q`
- Visual Studio Code: `Ctrl + M`

It took a little while to build muscle memory, but the benefit definitely outweighed the cost.

**important** : Because `jumpapp` works best with X11 window manager, you will need to switch from Wayland(default window manager) to X11 window manager using instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04) or [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/)